# What is the Cesaro sum of $(-1+1-1+1-1\ldots )$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, cesaro-summable

I have recently familiarized myself with the peculiar result of:

$1-1+1-1+1\ldots=\frac{1}{2}$

Following this enlightment I was now interested in finding out whether the following infinite series has the same Cesaro sum as the latter:

**$-1+1-1+1-1\ldots=$**

I did a few calculations and manipulations and ultimately arrived at a Cesaro sum of $-\frac{1}{2}$. However I have no method of verifying my result as I am not familiar with the technicalities of this subject.

The manipulations I performed to arrive at this result are:

let $(-1+1-1\ldots)=S$

$-1-S=-1-(-1+1-1\ldots)$

$-1-S=-1+1-1\ldots$

$-1-S=S$

$2S=-1$

$S=-\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: It is just the negative of the first series, after all.

Comment: At the very least, we can confirm that it is a reasonable result, as 1) the new series is the negative of the first, or 2) the new series is $-1$ plus the first series. Whether either of these manipulations _actually_ alter the Cesaro sum in the expected way is, of course, something that must be proven.

Comment: I made that assumption but I read up that making such assumptions while working on something that is very intricate such as this could lead to a hairy situation to say the least. Unless if I am mistaken in that conclusion of course. @wnoise

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. Are you having trouble applying the definition of the Cesaro sum?

Comment: Where is the problem ? The partial sum oscillates between $-1$ and $0$ and the average is $-\frac{1}{2}$. That's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Cesaro sum is what the running sums average out to. The running sums of $1,-1,1,-1,\ldots$ are $1,0,1,0,\ldots,$ which averages out to 1/2.

Likewise, the running sums of $-1,1,-1,1,\ldots$ are $-1,0,-1,0,\ldots,$ which averages out to $-1/2.$

If you want a more rigorous definition of "averages out", then what we mean is that as $n\to \infty$, $\frac{s_1+\ldots+s_n}{n}$ goes to a limit. Here (in the first series) $$ s_1/1 = 1\\(s_1+s_2)/2 = (1+0)/2 = 1/2
\\(s_1+s_2+s_2)/3 = 2/3\\(s_1+s_2+s_3+s_4)/4 = 1/2$$
and then $3/5, 1/2,4/7, 1/2,\ldots.$ That converges to $1/2.$

And, as we've seen, the running sums of the second series are the exact opposite, so it's the same thing for the second series, only everything has the opposite sign.